# Styling a "PART_" in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, telerik-grid

I want to style part of a telerik RadDGridView, the part in question is exposed as a template part called 'PART_AddNewRow'.

Is it possible to apply a style to this part, I don't want to replace the control template just style what is there?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: As far as i remember, no :(